# Dynamic library loading failed

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, cmake, loadlibrary

I'm trying to make dynamic library with all dependencies linked statically (except system libs). After building it on Windows10 I checked its dependencies with *Dependecy Walker*. It gave me next output:

[image]

So all dependencies are system libs, as I need. After that I wrote a simple console app to load, use and free this library. On my machine it works fine, but on another it brings me an error 1114 at loading process which means **ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED** (A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.).

As far as I read about this error, it can be due to internal error or missed dependency. But all dependencies in my case are system libs. Also this lib placed in the same directory with the main executable.

My code is pretty standard:

```
void* load_lib() {
    void* lib_ptr = LoadLibrary("libd.dll");
    if (!lib_ptr) {
        std::cout << "LoadLibrary failed: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
    }
    return lib_ptr;
}

bool free_lib(void* instance) {
    bool res = FreeLibrary((HINSTANCE)instance);
    if (!res) {
        std::cout << "FreeLibrary failed: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
    }
    return res;
}
```

What could be the reason of this error?

Comment: A missing dependency yields another error. Place the code for your *.dll* (*DllMain*), or at least a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't have DllMain as it crossplatform library

Comment: Ok try stripping out of it everything except a simple function (to be called by a dummy client *app*), and see if the problem persists. Also, what did you build it with?

Comment: Good point. I've tried it on another machine and it works fully. How is it possible?

Comment: @Egor *Also this lib placed in the same directory with the main executable.* -- We have no proof of your claim of where the DLL is stored.   What happens if you change the `LoadLibrary` call to load from a full path instead of just `libd.dll`, i.e. `LoadLibrary("c:\\mydllpath\\libd.dll");`?  If after doing that, if things start to work, then more than likely you have another version of `libd.dll` installed on your system, and Windows could be finding that version first, and not the version you expected.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your advice. I will try it too. But it is very unlikely to have a lib with the same name